# Is there is a limit for the number of the auto-renewable subscriptions for one subscription group?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

I am trying to add a new auto-renewable subscription and assign it to one of my subscription groups.

The problem is that I could not find this group on the `Add to Subscription Group` list; however, it was working before.

I checked this specific subscription group and found out it has 100 subscriptions, so is that the limit of the subscriptions that a group could have? or do I have another issue?

I searched a lot but didn't find any helpful reference that addressed this point.

For clarification, we do have a lot of subscriptions because of the A/B testing we do for pricing.

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this 100 subscription limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems true as when I removed one of the SKUs at this group it shows again in the `Add to Subscription Group` list when creating a new SKU